# Strange bracket assignment call ('[<-') with matrix argument

Tags: r, list, matrix, assignment-operator

Recently I've stumbled upon this bit of code:

```
y <- NULL

y[cbind(1:2, 1:2)] <- list( list(1,2), list(2,3))
```

From the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333525/error-in-tmpk-subscript-out-of-bounds-in-r).

But it doesn't seem to differ from `y <- list(...)`, as the comparisons below show:

```
> identical(y, list( list(1,2), list(2,3)))
[1] TRUE
> identical(y, y[cbind(1:2, 1:2)])
[1] FALSE
```

What is going on in the bracket assignment here? Why it doesn't throw an error? And why is it different from the non-assigment version in the last line of code?

Comment: Isn't it similar to `y[1:2] <- list( list(1,2), list(2,3) )`. I don't see the function of `cbind` here.

Comment: @Arun, the function of `cbind` is masked by the repetition of `1:2`.  If instead we use `cbind(1:2, 2:3)` then it will have an effect (although no different than from `c`)

Comment: Ricardo, give me a moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Matrix indexing only applies when `y` has dim.**  Combine this with standard `R` recycling and the fact that all matrices are actually vectors, and this behavior makes sense.

When you initialize `y` to NULL, you ensure it has no dim.   Therefore, when you index `y` by a matrix, say `ind`, you get the same results as having called `y[as.vector(ind)]`

```
identical(y[ind], y[as.vector(ind)])
# [1] TRUE
```

**If there are repeat values in `ind` and you are also assigning**, then for each index, only the last value assigned ot it will remain.   For example  Lets assume we are executing

```
y <- NULL; y[cbind(1:2, 2:1)] <- list( list(1,2), list(3,4) )
#   y has no dimension, so `y[cbind(1:2, 2:1)]` 
#   is the equivalent of   `y[c(1:2, 2:1)]`
```

When you assign  `y[c(1, 2, 2, 1)] <- list("A", "B")` , in effect what happens is analogous to:

```
    y[[1]] <- "A"
    y[[2]] <- "B"
    y[[2]] <- "B"  # <~~ 'Overwriting' previous value 
    y[[1]] <- "A"  # <~~ 'Overwriting' previous value
```

Here is a further look at the indexing that occurs: (Notice how the first two letters are being repeated)

```
ind <- cbind(1:2, 1:2)
L <- as.list(LETTERS)
L[ind]
# [[1]]
# [1] "A"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "B"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "A"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "B"
```

Here is the same thing, now with assignment. **Notice how only the 3rd and 4th values being assigned have been kept**.

```
L[ind] <- c("FirstWord", "SecondWord", "ThirdWord", "FourthWord")
L[ind]
# [[1]]
# [1] "ThirdWord"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "FourthWord"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "ThirdWord"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "FourthWord"
```

Try a different index for further clarity:

```
ind <- cbind(c(3, 2), c(1, 3))  ## will be treated as c(3, 2, 1, 3) 
L <- as.list(LETTERS)
L[ind] <- c("FirstWord", "SecondWord", "ThirdWord", "FourthWord")
L[1:5]
#  [[1]]
#  [1] "ThirdWord"
#  
#  [[2]]
#  [1] "SecondWord"
#  
#  [[3]]
#  [1] "FourthWord"
#  
#  [[4]]
#  [1] "D"
#  
#  [[5]]
#  [1] "E"

L[ind]
#  [[1]]
#  [1] "FourthWord"
#  
#  [[2]]
#  [1] "SecondWord"
#  
#  [[3]]
#  [1] "ThirdWord"
#  
#  [[4]]
#  [1] "FourthWord"
```

#### Edit regarding @agstudy's questions:

Looking at the src for `[` we have the following comments:

> - The special [ subscripting where dim(x) == ncol(subscript matrix)
> - is handled inside VectorSubset. The subscript matrix is turned
> - into a subscript vector of the appropriate size and then
> - VectorSubset continues.

Looking at the function `static SEXP VectorSubset(SEXP x, SEXP s, SEXP call)`  the relevant check is the following:

```
/* lines omitted */ 
attrib = getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol);
/* lines omitted */
if (isMatrix(s) && isArray(x) && ncols(s) == length(attrib)) {
    /* lines omitted */
...
```

Comment: Ricardo, `unlist` on a matrix has no effect.

Comment: @Arun, I meant `as.vector`  fixed it.  (thanks for pointing it out)

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing to talk about subsetting here. Your first  code part just below *This perhaps can make it more clear*. That's what confused me at least. Probably, it's best to stick to just the assignment part? Just my thought.

Comment: Arun, how ironic that the _This can make it more clear_ is what is confusing, hahah.  Let me see if I can give it an edit

Comment: :) sorry, I dint mean to. The underlying concept is recycling put to good use, but the way it gets overwritten during assignment is probably less intuitive to begin with. And to me, showing the subsetting first swayed me off...

Comment: @Arun, I was laughing at the irony because it was completely true. I restructured my answer